# Poynting Theorem Derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

I found this equation when I read about Poynting's theorem in Griffith's book.
$$
\textbf{B}\cdot\frac{\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(B^2)
$$
Can anyone please explain how to get this relation? I still don't get how to.

Comment: write it out in components and use $d (f(t))^2/dt=2 f df/dt$.

Comment: Start with the right hand side, write $B^2 = \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{B}$ and use the (dot) product rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the product rule applied to a vector field. If we write $B^2 = \mathbf{B \cdot B} = B_x^2 + B_y^2 + B_z^2$ we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(B_x^2 + B_y^2 + B_z^2\right) &= B_x \frac{\partial B_x}{\partial t} + B_y \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial t} + B_z \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial t}, \\
&= \mathbf{B \cdot}\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}.
\end{align}

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: @JovanAlfianDjaja You're welcome! If the answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).